# Can Convolutional Neural Networks (CNN) be represented by a Mathematical formula?

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

Please, let me know if this question should be posted in a differnt stack such as the https://datascience.stackexchange.com/.

Let's say that I already trained my CNN. Is there anyway of my ouput to be represented as a formula just like a perceptron can (x1w1 + x2w2 + ... = PREDICTION).

It does not matter if the formula is more complicated than the perceptron one, but in general would it be possible to train a CNN in Python or Matlab, get the weights and create an arithmetic, exponential, whatever formula made with those acquired weights?

I want to do this because I am trying classify in a PIC32 (a low cost microchip) which I think that does not have the capacity to perform a CNN within itself.

Or, for example, should I pursue the idea of some sort of "C library" that can do CNNs?

Comment: I think every computer program is effectively equivalent to a mathematical formula, although they can be arbitrarily complex, like millions of terms.

Comment: Yes this question fits better into datascience.stackexchange.com. For the calculation you can look at this page: http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/ it gives a nice visualization over the matrix multiplication that is used in CNNs

Comment: Either [cs.se] or [datascience.se] would probably be better places.

Answer (score 0):

If you can sacrifice some memory, you can certainly [convert a convolution into a matrix multiplication](https://github.com/Yangqing/caffe/wiki/Convolution-in-Caffe:-a-memo).

> It turns out to have its own pros (faster than any trivial
>   implementation unless you optimize really seriously) and cons (large
>   memory consumption).